# Flex: dataProvider variable named "result" makes trouble. Why?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var result : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([1,2,3]);
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:List dataProvider="{result}"/>
</mx:Application>
```

I have this code. The problem is: if my variable for dataProvider is named "result", then in the running application the List contains the only element "[object Binding]". By if I rename "result" for anything else (for example "res"), the List is displayed as expected - "1", "2", "3". Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer: THIS IS A BUG IN FLEX.  I HAVE REPORTED IT.**

This is odd... If we use the Spark List control, it won't even compile.  It tells us that it can't convert `Array` to `IList`.  `result` is obviously a variable some place, but where?

So I looked into the code that is generated using the -keep-generated-actionscript=true compiler flag.

Inside the ViewName-generate.as file, you will find an interesting method:

```
private function _ViewName_bindingsSetup():Array
{
    var result:Array = [];

    result[0] = new mx.binding.Binding(this,
        function():Object
        {

            return (result);
        },
        null,
        "_ViewName_List1.dataProvider"
        );


    return result;
}
```

This is where the Binding objects are making into your `result` variable.

We can see in the binding object that there is a function that returns `(result)`.  In any other case, this would be something else like `(results)`.  BUT, in this case, it is returning the local array of `Binding` objects.  That is why `this.result` works.  It is pulling out of the local scope!

So, this is obviously a bug.  I have submitted it to Adobe as such: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-29870

Answer (score 1):

I am just experimenting with Lists and Arrays in Flex. I tried `this.result`, it worked fine. I assume the result is maybe reserved.

Rob

Comment: Yes. If anything else works than 'result' must be a reserved keyword. Just change the name